# startActivityForResult for Notification Listener

Tags: android, start-activity, startactivityforresult, notification-listener

Is it possible to get a result from the notification listener Settings screen?

Currently, my project is using

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

I tried using startActivityForResult but was unable to get a RESULT_OK resultCode, for my specified requestCode.

I would like to know if notification access was given to my app or not(togglebutton is on or off when I return to the activity in my app)

Answer (score 3):

In onActivityResult, you can get the list of enabled listners by doing the following.

```
    String listeners = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            "enabled_notification_listeners");
    if (listeners != null)
        CommonMethods.printLog("e",TAG,"Listeners are : " + listeners);
```

and then check if access was given. Your own listener will be in this list if access was given.

I could not get a result of RESULT_OK from the notification listener Settings screen.

Comment: Hey. This worked! I would still like to know if it's possible to get a response of RESULT_OK. I can't +1your answer though.

Comment: What is `"enabled_notification_listeners"`?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using startActivityForResult but was unable to get a RESULT_OK resultCode, for my specified requestCode.

Few activities work with `startActivityForResult()`. *Both* sides have to implement support for it. Unless some documentation (e.g., on the `Intent` action) indicates that there is some output from the activity, you should assume that `startActivityForResult()` will have no useful impact.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to but I can't  +1 the answers/responses given.